# String lists applescript

Tags: string, macos, list, applescript, repeat

I am trying to have a list of applescript items but the things i'm adding are strings with multiple words.  When I try to view lets say item 1 of my list, it ends up being all of the items in the list.  I'm doing this from a repeat which might make a difference but I am very confused so anything that you think might work just post it.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it. This shows 2 types of repeat loops and how you use them. Good luck!

```
set myList to {"some words", "more of them", "and a lot of words"}

repeat with i from 1 to count of myList
    set thisItem to item i of myList
    -- do something with thisItem
end repeat

-- or another way to do a repeat loop

repeat with anItem in myList
    set thisItem to contents of anItem
    -- Notice if we use a repeat loop like this (e.g. anItem) then anItem
    -- is just a reference to the words. To actually get the words
    -- we need to get the contents of anItem
end repeat
```

Comment: Do you know the correct way to add another item to the end of the list?

Comment: set end of myList to "another item"... You should go here (http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=25631) and do the tutorials called "AppleScript Tutorial for Beginners". It's how I learned. There's one for lists.